# Why jdbc calling stored procedure "insert local table, select local table" CallableStatement.execute returns false?

Tags: java, sql-server, stored-procedures, jdbc

Question, Stored procedure, Java code as follows.

In SQL Server Express Edition, Java SE 8.

**PROCEDURE1**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Test1]
AS
DECLARE @UserList TABLE (UserId char(8))
    INSERT @UserList SELECT '00000001'
    SELECT UserId FROM @UserList
    --and SELECT STATEMENT join to @UserList
GO
```

**PROCEDURE2**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Test1]
AS
    SELECT '00000001'
    --and SELECT STATEMENT join to hard-code '00000001'
GO
```

**Java**

```
try (Connection con = ((DataSource) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/myapp")).getConnection();
    CallableStatement cstmt = con.prepareCall("{call [dbo].[Test1]}");
    ) {

  boolean f = cstmt.execute();
  ResultSet rs = cstmt.getResultSet();
```

**Question**

PROCEDURE1 call by jdbc, cstmt.execute() returns *false*.

PROCEDURE2 call by jdbc, cstmt.execute() returns *true*.
Why?

and **For What**

I want temporary table for dynamic in-clause parameter using by stored procedure.

Comment: You either need to add `SET NOCOUNT ON` to prevent the insert from generating an update count (which will be returned **before** the result set), or you need to correctly process all results of a stored procedure; see both duplicates.

Comment: Thanks for telling me. This question should be closed for duplicate.